# Как вызвать winapi функцию на ассемблере в Delphi

Tags: winapi, delphi, ассемблер

Как из ассемблерной вставки на Delphi, вызвать winapi функцию, например MessageBox?

Как

> MessageBox(0, 'Hello!', 0, 0);

вызвать из ассемблерной вствки на Delphi?

Comment: Попробуйте так:

    asm
    push 0
    push 0
    push 'Hello!'
    push 0
    call MessageBox
    end;

Не совсем уверен по поводу push 'Hello!'

Comment: Подозреваю, что нужно сделать `push` адреса, где лежит строка с нужным текстом, заканчивающаяся нулем.

Answer (score 2):

Можно сделать тот же самый код в делфи, скомпилировать, запустить и посмотреть, что получилось в окне CPU.

Answer (score 2):

Пример на FreePascal, для делфи не должно особо отличаться.

```
function AsmMessageBox(hWnd: THandle; lpText: PChar; lpCaption: PChar; uType: Cardinal): Integer;
begin
  {$ASMMODE Intel} // для включения синтаксиса Intel (в FreePascal), в делфи вроде и так по умлочанию
  asm
    mov r9d,uType
    mov r8,lpCaption
    mov rdx,lpText
    mov rcx,hWnd
    call MessageBox
    mov result,eax
  end;
end;
```